# How to use integer resources within string resources in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-resources

How can I use some integer that I have stored in my integers.xml file in my strings.xml file.

**For example:**

I have `<integer name="some_integer">5</integer>` 
and I would like to use this in my strings.xml file:

`<string name="some_string">This is my string num @integers/some_integer in a row</string>`

Apparently my way is not good enough so I need a little help please. I belive there is a possible solutions I just don't know the right one.

Appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

short version is that you can't mix resources like this, but you can use in Java:

```
getResources.getString(R.string.some_string,
                       getResources.getInteger(R.integer.some_integer)
                      );
```

and then in your String XML

```
<string name="some_string">This is my string num %d in a row</string>
```

that way the `%d` get replaced by the integer you pass in the `getString`

Comment: ps.: I wrote all this by heart, there might be some typo.

Comment: Wish I could accept both your answers. What it actually worked out was `<string name="my_name">Text here num %1$d and num %2$d </string> and your getString(R.string.my_name), getResources().getInteger(R.integer.num1), getResources().getInteger(R.integer.num2));`

Answer (score 4):

Others said your approach do not work. This is an old answer to face similar problem:

```
<string name="meatShootingMessage">You shot %1$d pounds of meat!</string>

int numPoundsMeat = 123;
String strMeatFormat = getResources().getString(R.string.meatShootingMessage);
String strMeatMsg = String.format(strMeatFormat, numPoundsMeat);
```

See this references:

- http://sagittech.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-use-variables-in-android.html
- http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-format-strings/

Comment: Mix my answer with provided by @Budius